# Sylius: Additional checkout step missing listener

Tags: symfony, listener, symfony4, checkout, sylius

I want to add a checkout step to the sylius checkout process. It's working in the sense that when I am at cart overview and click checkout my added step is shown. But when I click "Next" I am getting an error "Unable to generate a URL for the named route “sylius_order_index” as such route does not exist."

What I did so far (for now to avoid distraction I called my checkout step "test"):

## config/packages/_sylius.yaml:

```
winzou_state_machine:
    sylius_order_checkout:
        states:
            test_selected: ~ 
        transitions:     
            select_test:
                from: [cart, test_selected, addressed, shipping_selected, shipping_skipped, payment_selected, payment_skipped]
                to: test_selected
            address:
                from: [cart, test_selected, addressed, shipping_selected, shipping_skipped, payment_selected, payment_skipped]
                to: addressed
            select_shipping:
                from: [addressed, test_selected, shipping_selected, payment_selected, payment_skipped]
                to: shipping_selected
            select_payment:
                from: [payment_selected, test_selected, shipping_skipped, shipping_selected]
                to: payment_selected           
        callbacks:
            after:
                sylius_process_cart:
                    on: ["select_shipping", "address", "select_payment", "skip_shipping", "skip_payment", "select_test"]
                    do: ["@sylius.order_processing.order_processor", "process"]
                    args: ["object"]

sylius_shop:
    product_grid:
        include_all_descendants: true
    checkout_resolver:
        route_map:
            cart:
                route: sylius_shop_checkout_test
            test_selected:
                route: sylius_shop_checkout_address
```

## routes/Checkout/checkout.yml:

```
sylius_shop_checkout_start:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: sylius_shop_checkout_test

sylius_shop_checkout_test:
    path: /test
    methods: [GET, PUT]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:updateAction
        _sylius:
            event: test
            flash: false
            template: "Checkout/Test/test.html.twig"
            form:
                type: App\Form\TestType
            repository:
                method: findCartForAddressing
                arguments:
                    - "expr:service('sylius.context.cart').getCart().getId()"
            state_machine:
                graph: sylius_order_checkout
                transition: select_test
#after this all other states as they are in native Sylius in this file. The original checkout.yml is completely overridden with this one.
```

I followed the compiler in MY as opposed to NATIVE checkout steps and the difference is that in

## Bundle/Controller/ResourceController.php line 311:

```
    $postEventResponse = $postEvent->getResponse();
    if (null !== $postEventResponse) {
        return $postEventResponse;
    }
```

the Response object is null (thereby the if is not gotten into and the compiler moves on generating the arbirary/misleading error message mentioned above). So I noticed that occurs because in

## symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 72:

```
if ($listeners) {
    $this->callListeners($listeners, $eventName, $event);
}
```

$listeners is an empty array in my case whereas with every other native sylius step there is at least 1 listener subscribed here. I just don’t know where to add it. Can anybody point me to where/how that is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. Everything that was missing was the following in services.yaml:

```
app.request.matcher:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestMatcher

sylius.listener.checkout_redirect:
    class: Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Checkout\CheckoutRedirectListener
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'sylius.order.post_address',  method: 'handleCheckoutRedirect'}
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'sylius.order.post_select_shipping',  method: 'handleCheckoutRedirect'}
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'sylius.order.post_payment',  method: 'handleCheckoutRedirect'}
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'sylius.order.post_test',  method: 'handleCheckoutRedirect'}
    arguments:
        - '@request_stack'
        - '@sylius.router.checkout_state'
        - '@app.request.matcher'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CompilerPass and add a tag to the service

```
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CustomPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container
            ->getDefinition('sylius.listener.checkout_redirect')
            ->addTag('kernel.event_listener', [
                'event' => 'sylius.order.post_test',
                'method' => 'handleCheckoutRedirect',
            ]);
    }
}
```